# How to select rows with a certain percentage of a string column? (pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataset with many car brands.
I want to select the brands that take up a certain percentage.
For example %5.

Syntax of what I'm trying to do:
dataframe[(dataframe["brands"] >= %5) & (dataframe["brands"] <= %100)]

But since the brands are strings I can't use that syntax.
Any idea how to select rows with a certain percentage on a specific column(that is a string..)?

Comment: you'll need to convert them to numbers first `perc = dataframe['brands'].str.lstrip('%').astype(float)` then `dataframe[perc >= 5]`

Answer (score 0):

IIUC let's try groupby transform to get the size of each group, divide by the length of the dataframe to get the percentage of the frame the given brand takes up, then filter on that value:

```py
import pandas as pd

# Sample Data with
# 50 As, 40 Bs, 5 Cs, 3 Ds, 2 Es
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'brands': ['A'] * 50 + ['B'] * 40 + ['C'] * 5 + ['D'] * 3 + ['E'] * 2}
)

df['group_freq'] = df.groupby('brands')['brands'].transform('size') / len(df)
out = df[df['group_freq'] >= 0.05]
print(out)
```

Output:

```
   brands  group_freq
0       A        0.50
1       A        0.50
2       A        0.50
3       A        0.50
4       A        0.50
..    ...         ...
90      C        0.05
91      C        0.05
92      C        0.05
93      C        0.05
94      C        0.05

[95 rows x 2 columns]
```

---

Without assigning a new column:

```py
import pandas as pd

# Sample Data with
# 50 As, 40 Bs, 5 Cs, 3 Ds, 2 Es
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'brands': ['A'] * 50 + ['B'] * 40 + ['C'] * 5 + ['D'] * 3 + ['E'] * 2}
)

s = df.groupby('brands')['brands'].transform('size') / len(df)
out = df[s >= 0.05]
print(out)
```